# Network Analysis: Solve Route - No Solution

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, network-analyst

I'm using ArcGIS 9.3.1

In my network there are isolated network(not connected to main network) and restricted(non-traversable network element position)

When I plot 1 point close to a isolated or restricted road. It will snap to it and return me no solution found or restricted network.

May I know is there a simple solution to ask the solver to choose another line/point if it can't find a solution?

In arcgis 9.3.1 there is no "Exclude restricted portion of the network" and I don't wish to use the query builder to ignore FType that carry restricted options.

So the main objective is to make the solver pick another line/point to snap on to.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your situation?

Comment: I don't think there is a (practical) way to tell it to find another origin. You may not like this, but you may want to remove non-connected portions of your network. If you went that with that approach, there is no out-of-the-box solution (as far as I know). In my experience I've been able to use Python and NetworkX on pretty large networks to find isolated sub-networks, followed by a removal process.

Comment: @AllanAdair Sorry for the late reply, could you show sample onn how to find isolate neworks? I know this is 2 years ago question =x